# How to change the year for a date in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

Lets say I have a string representing a date but without the information for the year. I need to convert this string to a date but I explicitly need to set the year of this date. Here is an example:

```
select to_date('20.01. 23:59:00', 'DD.MM. HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

The year of this date is automatically set to the current year. What do I have to do if I want to set the year for example to 1972?

Comment: it's just a string, so you can add the year with a simple string operation: `to_date('20.01.' || yearvalue || ' 23:59:00', 'dd.mm.yyetc...')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard-code `'1972.'` and concatenate before your string; then add `YYYY.` to the format model.

```
select to_date('1972.' || '20.01. 23:59:00', 'YYYY.DD.MM. HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

If instead you have another column with the year, say `yr`, and it is in number format, then write `to_char(yr) || '.' || ....` within `to_date()`.